# Печать текста используя C++

Tags: c++, принтер

Создал примитивный текстовый редактор. Как распечатать на принтере введенный текст, стоит учитывать, что программа предназначена для разных ПК от Windows XP до 7 и с разными принтерами. Что посоветуете?

Comment: Само просто - печать в порт. Есть печать "как изображения" через canvas - (недостаток- глюки на матричном). Можно печать как rtf. Можно печатать через готовый текстовый процессор. Можно печатать c использованием esc-комманд. На самом деле много вариантов. Зависит от вашей задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас приложения на Windows Form application(.Net Frameworks) то можно через PrintDocument Class
MS VC++ [подробнее тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1)